# ¿Cómo acceder a la tabla relacionada en relación M:N? - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mvc, entity-framework

Tengo 2 tablas llamadas `contrato` y `arrendadores`, que tienen una tabla pivote llamada `contrato_arrendador`. Usando *Entity Framework*, ¿cómo puedo acceder desde `contrato` hasta `arrendadores`?

Llegué hasta `contacto_contrato` usando esta sentencia:

```
context.Contrato.Include(x=>x.ContratoArrendadores).ToList();
```

Pensé que podría hacer algo tipo:

```
context.Contrato.Include(x=>x.ContratoArrendadores).ThenInclude(y=>y.Arrendadores).ToList();
```

Pero ahí ya no me aparece la tabla arrendadores. Estoy seguro que algo me debe estar haciendo falta pero no sé qué es ni en donde buscar, ¿alguna ayuda al respecto? gracias de antemano :)

Comment: Indica por favor los Modelos de Datos de esas tres tablas. También lo que tienes en el DbContext.

Comment: Quizás [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/345509/131018) pueda ayudarte

Answer (score 0):

`ContratoArrendadores` Debe ser registrada como tabla en DbContext y sobre la tabla `ContratoArrendadores` haces tus queries.

```
DbSet<ContratoArrendadores> ContratoArrendadores { get; set; }
```

Ejemplo, traer todos los `contratos` que pertenezcan a determinado `arrendador`.

```
 context.ContratoArrendadores.Include(x=> x.Contrato)
        .Where(x=>x.Arrendador.Id.Equals(ArrendadorId))
        .ToList();
```

Comment: La pregunta trata de acceder a varios niveles de profundidad de relación.