# Uso join, pero me gustaría saber si puedo usar include en vez de join

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

buen día. soy nuevo por aquí y agradezco de antemano a todos, tengo algunas dudas sobre el uso de Include en Enitity Framework
tengo este código

```
public static List<Producto> ListProducts()
        {
            using (GourmetEntities db = new GourmetEntities())
            {
                var Listproducs = (from lt in db.tblProductoes
                                   join id in db.tblUnidads on lt.IdUnidadMedida equals id.Id
                                   join IdCat in db.tblCategorias on lt.IdCategoria equals IdCat.Id
                                   orderby lt.Codigo
                                   select new Producto
                                   {
                                       Codigo = lt.Codigo,
                                       Producto = lt.Producto,
                                       NombreCortoMedida = id.NombreCorto,
                                       NombreCategoria = IdCat.Descripcion,
                                       PrecioVenta = lt.PrecioVenta,
                                       Stock = lt.Stock,

                                   }).ToList();

                return Listproducs;
            }
```

ahora he estado leyendo sobre include, lo que yo entiendo es que puedo sustituir todo el codigo anterior usando include(x => x.tablaRelacionada)
les aclaro yo tengo una tabla producto y la relaciono con la tabla categorías por el id
pero para mostrar no voy a mostrar el id, en su lugar mostrare el nombre de la categoría
para que quede claro estas tablas no son maestro detalle.
si esto es factible me pueden por favor mostrar un ejemplo de cómo se hace.
yo he intentado haciendo esto

```
public static List<tblProducto> ListaInclude()
        {
            var productos = new List<tblProducto>();
            using(GourmetEntities db = new GourmetEntities())
            {
                db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
                productos = db.tblProductoes.Include(x => x.tblCategoria).ToList();
                return productos;
            }

        }
```

pero no funciona 
agradezco la ayuda.

Comment: revisa esta info https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.objectquery-1.include?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Muchas gracias Ramiro Barrone.me quedo mas claro en que momento debo usar include.
Gracias. pueden apuntar como respuesta por favor no veo la opción.

Comment: te hice un comentario. no una respuesta porque me parecio que debias leer la doc antes de que yo te hiciera codigo.

Comment: Ramiro Buen día. la verdad antes de hacer hacer una pregunta intento por mis medios entender y resolver mis dudas, pero cuando no me queda claro busco ayuda.
Nuevamente gracias
Roberto

Comment: Lo que te comente es porque no ibas a poder encontrar el boton para aceptar una respuesta. Porque era un comentario.

Comment: Muy bien Ramiro Gracias de todas formas muy amable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El propósito principal del método (de extensión) `#Include` es hacer *queries* con profundidad de relaciones *{N:M}*, *{N:1}*, ...

Voy a simplificar tu escenario para poder hacer un pequeño ejemplo. Supongamos estas dos entidades

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    // 1:N relationship
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    // N:1 relationship
    public IList<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

`Product` tiene una referencia a `Category` y también añade el campo `CategoryId`, que lo necesitará *Entity Framework* para crear la *foreign key*.
El nombre de la propiedad es importante que sea exactamente `CategoryId`, hace referencia a la propiedad `Category` y al campo `Id` (de la categoría). Si necesitamos que tenga otro nombre, deberemos especificarlo a la hora de diseñar el `DbContext`.

Ahora, para diseñar las relaciones, necesitamos sobreescribir el método `#OnModelCreating` de la clase `DbContext`.
Creamos una clase nuestra que herede de `DbContext` y lo sobreescribimos.

```
public class SampleContext : DbContext
{
    public SampleContext(DbContextOptions<SampleContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<Product>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(p => p.Id);
            entity.HasOne(p => p.Category)
                  .WithMany(c => c.Products);
        });

        builder.Entity<Category>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(c => c.Id);
        });
    }
}
```

Haciendo uso del `builder` que nos da la API de *Entity Framework*, describimos las entidades y las relaciones entre ellas.
En mi caso, indico qué propiedad del modelo es la clave primaria, el `Id` y las relaciones.
Indico que `Product` tiene una (y sólo una) `Category` y, a su vez, `Category` tiene varios `Product`. El método `#HasOne<Product>` ya me devuelve un objeto `ReferenceNavigationBuilder<T1, T2>` donde `T1` es `Product` y `T2` es `Category` porque es la propiedad que he descrito en el `Func<>` que paso por parámetro, de modo que podemos usar programación *fluent* para definir la relación inversa.
Cuando definimos la entidad `Category` no hace falta volver a indicar la relación, ya está indicada.

> Para hacer efectivo este diseño a la base de datos hace falta crear una migración con el comando `Add-Migration MigrationName` o `dotnet migrations add MigrationName` y después volcar las migraciones a la base de datos.
>   Personalmente, el volcado a la base de datos lo hago directamente en mi código cada vez que arranca el servicio del siguiente modo

```
builder.RegisterBuildCallback(scope =>
{
    var context = scope.Resolve<SampleContext>();
    var db = context.Database;
    // Applies migration
    // Performs as the Update-Database command
    db.Migrate();
});
```

> Usando *Autofac*, registro una *callback* que se ejecuta una vez se construye el contenedor de dependencias principal. En ese momento ya puedo resolver el `SampleContext`.
>   En caso de no usar ningún *framework* de inyección de dependencias, deberás proveerle al contexto la conexión a la base de datos y luego llamar al método `#Update` de la `DatabaseFacade` del contexto.

A la hora de hacer las *queries*, no tendremos más que aplicar el método `#Include` e indicar qué propiedad incluir en la *query*.

```
var products = await _context.Products
                             .Include(product => product.Category)
                             .ToListAsync();
```

Con el *namespace* de *EntityFrameworkCore* también viene el método de extensión `#ThenInclude`, que sirve para bajar un nivel de profundidad más en las relaciones.
Supongamos este escenario

```
public class Product
{
    // ...
    public IList<Provider> Providers { get; set; }
}

public class Provider
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public int ManufacturerId { get; set; }
}

public class Manufacturer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Ahora, `Product` tiene también una relación *{N:1}* con la tabla `Providers` y, a su vez, cada `Provider` tiene asociado un `Manufacturer`.
Cuando hagamos la *query* a la base de datos, podremos traer todas las tablas relacionadas en profundidad usando los métodos `#ThenInclude` e `#Include`

```
var products = await _context.Products
                             .Include(product => product.Category)
                             .Include(product => product.Providers)
                             .ThenInclude(provider => provider.Manufacturer)
                             .ToListAsync();
```

---

Si quisieramos construir un objeto con los datos procesados para no tener que tratar con las entidades puras, se puede hacer uso del método `#Select` de *Linq*.

```
class ProductDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string CategoryDescription { get; set; }
}
```

Teniendo este *DTO* (*Data Tranfer Object*), podríamos mapearlo de la forma

```
IList<ProductDto> products = _context.Products
                                     .Include(product => product.Category)
                                     .Select<Product, ProductDto>(product =>
                                        new ProductDto
                                        {
                                            Name = product.Name,
                                            Description = product.Description,
                                            CategoryName = product.Category.Name,
                                            CategoryDescription = product.Category.Description
                                        }
                                     ).ToList();
```

Lo importante a ver es que ya podemos acceder a la propiedad `Category` de nuestro producto, ya que *Entity Framework* lo ha inicializado por nosotros.
Aunque siempre es mejor hacer esta operación en un segundo paso, una vez hemos salido de la capa de acceso a datos.

Espero que sirva.

Comment: VRoxa buen día, gracias por la ayuda. son pocos los caracteres 
y si yo traigo mi modelo de una db, no me viene esa linea Category Category {Get;Set;} debo agregarla luego, la verdad soy muy nuevo en Entity Framework y quiero aprender, el include cuando hago la consulta me trae el Id de la Category o me trae el nombre, en el ultimo código veo que yo elijo que campos voy a mostrar.
muchas gracias VRoxa.
Roberto

Comment: Debería haber matizado que, tal y como yo te lo expliqué, uso la estrategia [*code first*](https://www.campusmvp.es/recursos/post/entity-framework-code-first-database-first-y-model-first-en-que-consiste-cada-uno.aspx) de *Entity Framework*

Comment: VRoxa gracias, entiendo, por aquí no puedo pasar mi código por limite de caracteres ahora lo pondre donde dice Responde a tu Pregunta, espero que sea así
un favor me gustaría hacer un método de estas dos entidades Producto y Categoría y pasarlo a un datagridView, esto con el fin de entender bien lo que me explica, por favor y agradezco la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Deseo responder a @VRoxa estas mis entidades

```
    public partial class tblProducto
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public tblProducto()
    {
        this.tblDetalleVentas = new HashSet<tblDetalleVenta>();
        this.tblDetalleIngresoProductos = new HashSet<tblDetalleIngresoProducto>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Categoria_Id { get; set; }
    public int UnidadMedida_Id { get; set; }
    public string Codigo { get; set; }
    public string ProductoDescripcion { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> PrecioVenta { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Stock { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime FechaCreado { get; set; }
    public string NombreImagen { get; set; }
    public byte[] Imagen { get; set; }
    public int Estado_Id { get; set; }
    public int Usuario_Id { get; set; }

    public virtual tblCategoria tblCategoria { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<tblDetalleVenta> tblDetalleVentas { get; set; }
    public virtual tblEstado tblEstado { get; set; }
    public virtual tblUnidad tblUnidad { get; set; }
    public virtual tblUsuario tblUsuario { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<tblDetalleIngresoProducto> tblDetalleIngresoProductos { get; set; }
}
```

y mi categoría es esta

```
    public partial class tblCategoria
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public tblCategoria()
    {
        this.tblProductos = new HashSet<tblProducto>();
        this.tblDetalleVentas = new HashSet<tblDetalleVenta>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<tblProducto> tblProductos { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<tblDetalleVenta> tblDetalleVentas { get; set; }
}
```

y cual sería el DTO de mi producto por favor

Gracias